# docker-compose not behaving in compliance with dockerfiles

Tags: r, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm a level 0 Docker user, so bear with me on this one:

I'm trying to create a shared container environment with `docker-compose`. The `docker-compose.yaml` looks like this:

```
# docker-compose.yml

#ubuntu(16.04) + python(3)
version: '3'
services:
 ubuntu:
   image: 434c03a615a2
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: dockerfileBase   
   volumes:
     - "./data/data_vol/:/app"
   tty: true

#tensorflow
 tensorflow:
   image: tensorflow/tensorflow
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: dockerfileTensorflow
   ports:
     - "8888:8888"
   tty: true

#rstudio
 rstudio:
   image: rocker/rstudio
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: dockerfileRstudio1   
   environment:
     - PASSWORD=supersecret
   ports:
     - "8787:8787"
   tty: true
```

As far as I can tell everything is working, but the dockerfile, with which I import Rstudio doesn't seem to get executed the same way inside the `.yaml` as it does outside of it. What I mean is that this Rstudio dockerfile:

```
#pull rstudio
FROM rocker/rstudio:3.4.3
LABEL maintainer="Landsense"

#set Env variables 
ENV http_proxy=http://##.###.###.##:####
ENV https_proxy=http://##.###.###.##:####
ENV ftp_proxy=http://##.###.###.##:####
ENV TZ="Europe/Rome"

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
  libgdal-dev \
  libproj-dev \
  libv8-dev \
  ssh && \
  apt-get clean all

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('raster')"
```

installs packages when it's built on its own, but fails to do so when ran from the docker-compose.yaml . Can someone comment on this type of behavior? RSPKT!

Comment: What does "fail to do so" mean? Fails how? Also - notice you have both `build` and `image` in the rstodio definition. This is fine, but you should probably change the `image` to something other than the official `rocker/rstudio` name, since you are actually building it from your own dockerfile. Not sure it will solve your issue, but its a step towards reducing confusion (also true for your other images).

Comment: @DannyB, by "fail" I meant that the `RUN` lines for installing packages never got executed. But you are 100% right - for some reason the `image` tag takes precedence over `build` . After I changed the `image` name everything ran as expected. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it is actually because the image was already cached, it did not build it. `docker-compose build` could have also fixed it, but having your own image names (or not at all) when using `build` directive in `docker-compose.yml` is still a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have both `image` and `build` in a docker-compose service precedence is given to `image`. In your scenario your since you have `image: rocker/rstudio` in your compose file it will pull the `rocker/rstudio:latest` image from [docker-hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/). But what do you want is a image build on top of the `rocker/rstudio` image (In Dockerfile it has been used as the base image).

It is not a good practice to tag your image as with existing tag in docker-hub (You may face difficulties as wrong image is cached in your local docker images as you experienced here). First decide whether you really want to name your image (Otherwise compose will tag the image for you where tag include a part of your service name so you can easily identify). If you want use it as following with a prefix in image tag. Same goes with other two services.

```
image: localhost/rocker/rstudio
build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: dockerfileRstudio1
```